# Error when running Check Package on package containing import from package containing Rcpp

Tags: r, package

Firstly, my appologies as this is my first time posting, and this is a little convoluted. I have tried to make an as simple demonstration of the issue as I can.
I am running R (3.3.2) with R studio (1.0.44), on Windows 10.

When I run 'Check Package' on a package that imports from another home built package that contains Rcpp I get a build error in the 'checking whether package can be installed' section.

This is what I have done...

First I made a folder on my PC to contain some new packages C:/Rtest/.

Using RStudio I created a New Package (type: Package, name: "testRpack"). I updated the license in DESCRIPTION to a valid code (GPL). I changed every instance of "hello" to "helloR" in the files in the folders "R" and "man", including the filenames (i.e. "hello.R" became "helloR.R", and "hello.Rd" became "helloR.Rd"). Then I did a Build & Reload, and then a Check Package. It reported no errors, warnings or notes.

Now, again using RStudio, I created a New Package (type: Package w/Rcpp, name: "testRcpp"). I updated the license in DESCRIPTION as before. Then I did a Build & Reload, and then a Check Package. It reported no errors, warnings or notes.

Finally I created another New Package using RStudio (type: Package, name: "testMe"). I changed every instance of "hello" to "helloMe" in files in folders "R" and "man", and updated the license in DESCRIPTION. I performed a Build & Reload, and then a Check Package. It reported no errors, warnings or notes.

Now, in Package "helloMe" I changed the 'Configure Build Tools' to 'Generate documentation with Roxygen'. I added Roxygen notes to the "helloMe.R" file as follows:

```
#' HelloMe, World!
#' @title HelloMe, World!
#' @aliases helloMe
#' @export
#' @description Prints 'HelloMe, world!'.
#' @examples
#'    helloMe()
#' @importFrom testRpack helloR
helloMe <- function() {
  print("HelloMe, world!")
  helloR()
}
```

and updated the DESCRIPTION file to Import testRpack by adding the lines:

```
Imports:
    testRpack
```

I ran the Build & Reload and then Check Package functions in RStudio and it reported no errors, warnings or notes.

Finally, I also Imported the testRcpp package by updating the Import section in the DESCRIPTION file to:

```
Imports:
    testRpack,
    testRcpp
```

and changing the "helloMe.R" file to:

```
#' HelloMe, World!
#' @title HelloMe, World!
#' @aliases helloMe
#' @export
#' @description Prints 'HelloMe, world!'.
#' @examples
#'    helloMe()
#' @importFrom testRpack helloR
#' @importFrom testRcpp hello
helloMe <- function() {
  print("HelloMe, world!")
  helloR()
  hello()
}
```

I now perform a Build & Reload and then a Check Package as before. This time the Check Package reports 1 error. The full readout is is as follows:

```
==> devtools::check()

Updating testMe documentation
Loading testMe
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing helloMe.Rd
Setting env vars ---------------------------------------------------------------
CFLAGS  : -Wall -pedantic
CXXFLAGS: -Wall -pedantic
Building testMe ----------------------------------------------------------------
"C:/R/Program/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore --quiet CMD build "C:\Rtest\testMe" --no-resave-data  \
  --no-manual 

* checking for file 'C:\Rtest\testMe/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'testMe':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building 'testMe_0.1.0.tar.gz'

Setting env vars ---------------------------------------------------------------
_R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_ : FALSE
_R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_: FALSE
Checking testMe ----------------------------------------------------------------
"C:/R/Program/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore --quiet CMD check  \
  "C:\Users\KURT~1.BAL\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6xObJv/testMe_0.1.0.tar.gz"  \
  --as-cran --timings --no-manual 

* using log directory 'C:/Rtest/testMe.Rcheck'
* using R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
* using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
* using session charset: ISO8859-1
* using options '--no-manual --as-cran'
* checking for file 'testMe/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* checking extension type ... Package
* this is package 'testMe' version '0.1.0'
* package encoding: UTF-8
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... OK
* checking if this is a source package ... OK
* checking if there is a namespace ... OK
* checking for executable files ... OK
* checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
* checking for portable file names ... OK
* checking whether package 'testMe' can be installed ... ERROR
Installation failed.
See 'C:/Rtest/testMe.Rcheck/00install.out' for details.
* DONE
Status: 1 ERROR
Warning: running command '"C:/R/Program/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" INSTALL -l "C:/Rtest/testMe.Rcheck" --no-html "C:\Rtest\TESTME~1.RCH\00_PKG~1\testMe"' had status 1

See
  'C:/Rtest/testMe.Rcheck/00check.log'
for details.

checking whether package 'testMe' can be installed ... ERROR
Installation failed.
See 'C:/Rtest/testMe.Rcheck/00install.out' for details.
R CMD check results
1 error  | 0 warnings | 0 notes

R CMD check succeeded
```

The folder 'C:/Rtest/testMe.Rcheck/' does not exist, and hence neither does the file '00install.out'. I noticed (from a File Explorer window) that it was created whilst the Check was in progress, but was then deleted.

Despite this reported error, when running the function "helloMe()" I get the desired output:

```
> helloMe()
[1] "HelloMe, world!"
[1] "HelloR, world!"
[1] "Hello, world
```

In other words, the package appears to work okay, but the Check Package is reporting the error.

The behaviour is the same when I also add "rcpp_hello()" to the "helloMe" function - I get the list output appended, as expected.

Can anyone shed any light on what I am missing here?

Thank you.